# How to display category and subcategory in post serializer django-rest-framework

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I need to extract categories and subcategories in Post serializer, because I need to put pagination, if I put pagination in category view, different amount of posts will come, so I need to put pagination in Post view, I need to return response so that it looks like this

and I want to create rest api to return nested json like this

```
[
{
  "id": 1,
  "title": "Taomlar",
  "subcat": [
      {
        id: 2,
        title: "Milliy",
        post: [
            {
              id: 1,
              title: 'Palov',
              summa: 300000,
              ...
            },     
              {
              id: 2,
              title: 'Palov',
              summa: 300000,
              ...
            },
          ]
      },     
    ]  
}     
]
```

**models.py**

```
class Category(Base):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Post(Base):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=225)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='post')
```

**serializers.py**

```
class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = '__all__'

class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = '__all__'
```

Can anyone please give me the solution for this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As much as I understand you need to get each Category with it's related posts.

Overwriting like this :

```
class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    posts = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = (
            'id',
            'title',
            'posts',
        )
    def get_posts(self, obj):
        serializer = PostSerializer(obj.posts.all(), context=self.context, many = True)
        return serializer.data
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'Category' object has no attribute 'products' this error s give me

Comment: I edited my answer, It should be posts not products  @XursandbekIbadullayev

Answer (score 0):

you can read more about nested serializer in **Django Rest Framework**

you should make it in this way

```
class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
      post_serializer = PostSerializer(many=True)
      class Meta:
          model = Category
          fields = ['your_field', 'post_serializer']
```

this a basic example, try to read more about it to know how you can implement nested relations